# Need help to gather data from a txt file and insert in a web page?

Tags: parsing, find, locate, collect

could someone advise me on the most efficient way to gather data from one source, select a specific piece of data and insert it in a web page? Specifically, I wish to:

1. Call up this buoy data text file: http://www.ndbc.noaa.gov/data/realtime2/46237.txt
2. Find the water temperature and insert that value in my web page.

First big question: What scripting language should I use? (I'm assuming Fortran is not an option :-)

Second not so big question: This same data set is available in graphic and xml format. Would either of these data formats be more useful than the .txt file?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Use Perl.

(Hey, you asked. Normally one programs in whatever language one would normally use.)

The XML format won't be much more useful than the text format.

Comment: Thanks Satya, googling 'Perl tutorial' now.

Answer (score 0):

This text file format is just about as simple as it could ever get. Just about any scripting or general purpose programming language will work. The critical part is to split each line on a regex "\s+". i.e. in Python it would be:

```
import re

theFileObject = open('/path/to/downloaded/file.txt')
for line in theFileObject.readlines():
    columns = re.split(r'\s+', line)
    # each column is columns[0] through columns[19]
```

So basically choose whatever programming language seems easiest to you. Any .NET language would be equally capable, as well as ruby, python, scheme, etc. I personally have a distaste for perl because I find it very difficult to read